# Can you append lines to a remote file using ftp_put() or something similar?

Tags: php, ftp

Here's the situation... I have two servers, server 1 and server 2.
server 1 downloads a csv file from server 2, deletes it off server 2, reads lines from it and does some processing.

While it is processing, the file on server 2 can be re-created or changed, adding more lines.
After it is done processing, server 1 needs to upload the file back to server 2.

However, ftp_put() will completely overwrite the file on server 2. What I really want to do is append to the file on server 2 and not overwrite it. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curl support appending for FTP:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPAPPEND, TRUE ); // APPEND FLAG
```

This might be what you're looking for. Are you familiar with curl?

The other option is to use `ftp://` / `ftps://` streams, since PHP 5 they allow appending. See [ftp://; ftps:// <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php). Might be easier to access.

Comment: The parameter was renamed in libcurl, probably same for PHP: CURLOPT_APPEND

A parameter set to 1 tells the library to append to the remote file instead of overwrite it. This is only useful when uploading to an FTP site.

(This option was known as CURLOPT_FTPAPPEND up to 7.16.4) -- http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html

Comment: I found [this post](http://www.cre8asiteforums.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=67006) which basically uses a combination of both curl and ftp://. I think it's going to work.

Comment: @BrianGlaz link is broken, you have another example?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `file_put_contents` with the `FILE_APPEND` flag?

Comment: how can you include the ftp username and password though?

Comment: @Brian: `ftp://user:password@example.com/pub/file.txt` - just put it into the path, check the docs I linked for ftp(s):// in my answer for details.

Comment: @hakre Oh, ok. I got it now. Thanks! `file_put_contents` seems a lot easier than setting all of the `curl_opts`. Is there any advantage / disadvantage to using one over the other?

Comment: That's what I meant with "more accessible" in my answer. I would prefer using streams unless you need curl for something specific as it's a library. Streams are a cool feature of PHP.

Comment: `curl` makes me very sad. Whenever I see a script that has 10 lines of `curl_setopt` I die a little inside.

Answer (score 2):

As shown in other answer, [`file_put_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) with `FILE_APPEND` flag is the easiest solution to append a chunk to the end of a remote file:

```
file_put_contents('ftp://username:pa‌​ssword@hostname/path/to/file', $chunk, FILE_APPEND);
```

If it does not work, it's probably because you do not have [URL wrappers enabled in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php).

---

Though, if you actually have a matching local copy of a file, just with the new contents appended, it's easier to use a "hidden" feature of the [`ftp_put`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php), the [`FTP_AUTORESUME`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ftp.constants.php#constant.ftp-autoresume):

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect('hostname');

ftp_login($conn_id, 'username', 'password');
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

$remote_path = '/path/to/file';
$local_path = 'file';
ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_path, $local_file, FTP_BINARY, FTP_AUTORESUME);

ftp_close($conn_id);
```

*(add error handling)*

---

If you do not have a matching local file, i.e. you are uploading a chunk of contents from memory, and you need a greater control over the writing (transfer mode, passive mode, etc), than you get with the `file_put_contents`, use the [`ftp_fput`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fput.php) with a handle to the [`php://temp` (or the `php://memory`) stream](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.memory):

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect('hostname');

ftp_login($conn_id, 'username', 'password');
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

$h = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
fwrite($h, $chunk);
rewind($h);

// prevent ftp_fput from seeking local "file" ($h)
ftp_set_option($conn_id, FTP_AUTOSEEK, false);

$remote_path = '/path/to/file';
$size = ftp_size($conn_id, $remote_path);
$r = ftp_fput($conn_id, $remote_path, $h, FTP_BINARY, $size);

fclose($h);
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

*(again, add error handling)*