# Transfer in-memory data to FTP server without using intermediate file

Tags: php, ftp

I am having some JSON data that I encoded it with PHP's `json_encode()`, it looks like this:

```
{
    "site": "site1",
    "nbrSicEnt": 85,
}
```

What I want to do is to write the data directly as a file onto an FTP server.

For security reasons, I don't want the file to be created locally first before sending it to the FTP server, I want it to be created on the fly. So without using `tmpfile()` for example.

When I read the php documentations for `ftp_put`:

```
bool ftp_put ( resource $ftp_stream , string $remote_file , 
               string $local_file , int $mode [, int $startpos = 0 ] )
```

Ones needs to create a local file (`string $local_file`) before writing it to the remote file.

I am looking for a way to directly write into the remote_file. How can I do that using PHP?

Answer (score 3):

The [`file_put_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) is the easiest solution:

```
file_put_contents('ftp://username:pa‌​ssword@hostname/path/to/file', $contents);
```

If it does not work, it's probably because you do not have [URL wrappers enabled in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php).

---

If you need greater control over the writing (transfer mode, passive mode, offset, reading limit, etc), use the [`ftp_fput`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fput.php) with a handle to the [`php://temp` (or the `php://memory`) stream](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.memory):

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect('hostname');

ftp_login($conn_id, 'username', 'password');
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

$h = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
fwrite($h, $contents);
rewind($h);

ftp_fput($conn_id, '/path/to/file', $h, FTP_BINARY, 0);

fclose($h);
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

*(add error handling)*

---

Or you can open/create the file directly on the FTP server. That's particularly useful, if the file is large, as you won't have keep whole contents in memory.

See [Generate CSV file on an external FTP server in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49970767/850848).

Answer (score 2):

According to [Can you append lines to a remote file using ftp_put() or something similar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234817/can-you-append-lines-to-a-remote-file-using-ftp-put-or-something-similar) and [Stream FTP Upload with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248700/stream-ftp-upload-with-php) you should be able to do something using either CURL or PHP's FTP wrappers using `file_put_contents()`.

```
$data = json_encode($object);
file_put_contents("ftp://user:pass@host/dir/file.ext", $data, FILE_APPEND);
```