# How to get picture from URL -> resize without saving -> upload to FTP?

Tags: php, ftp

I have problem!

I can get image and resize it by `imagecopyresampled()`.

But when I try to use `ftp_put()`: expects parameter 3 to be a valid path.

I try to use:

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($resource, NULL);
$resource = ob_get_contents();
```

It does not help. I don't need to save the image to a local machine.

Comment: if your not saving it, what are you doing with it?

Comment: without savin when I changing size on local machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [FTP protocol wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php), like:

```
imagejpeg($resource, "ftp://user:password@example.com/dir/file.jpg");
```

---

A more generic "upload in-memory contents to FTP" would be:

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($resource, NULL);
$contents = ob_get_contents();
file_put_contents("ftp://user:password@example.com/dir/file.jpg", $contents);
```

---

See also [Transfer in-memory data to FTP server without using intermediate file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27103587/850848).