# PHP copy file from HTTP URL to FTP server

Tags: php, ftp

I have this link: http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/6/0300002536/03/PSG11_CUG_EN_03.pdf and I want to copy this file to my FTP server. I tried:

```
$file = "http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/6/0300002536/03/PSG11_CUG_EN_03.pdf";
$data = file_get_contents($url);

$ftp_server = "ftp_server";
$ftp_user = "ftp_user";
$ftp_pass = "ftp_pass";

$ftp = ftp_connect($ftp_server,21) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 

if (ftp_login($ftp, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
  echo "Connecté en tant que $ftp_user@$ftp_server\n";
} else {
  echo "Connexion impossible en tant que $ftp_user\n";
}
```

The connection was successful, but after that I do not know how to start.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use [ftp_fput](http://php.net/manual/de/function.ftp-fput.php), but I'm not sure if this function is able to handle an URL (I don't think so), so I decided to put your existing variable into the memory and to fake a file handler:

```
$tmpFile = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
fputs($tmpFile, $data);
rewind($tmpFile);
if (ftp_fput($ftp, 'manual.pdf', $tmpFile, FTP_ASCII)) {
 echo "worked";
} else {
 echo "did not work";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have [URL wrappers enabled](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php), it's as easy as:

```
$file = "http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/6/0300002536/03/PSG11_CUG_EN_03.pdf";
$ftp_server = "ftp_server";
$ftp_user = "ftp_user";
$ftp_pass = "ftp_pass";

copy($file, "ftp://$ftp_user:$ftp_pass@$ftp_server/PSG11_CUG_EN_03.pdf");
```

---

If you need a greater control over the writing (transfer mode, passive mode, offset, reading limit, etc), use the [`ftp_fput`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fput.php) with a handle to the [`php://temp` (or the `php://memory`) stream](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.memory).

See [Transfer in-memory data to FTP server without using intermediate file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27103587/850848#43539323).