# Transfer files between two remote FTP servers in PHP

Tags: php, ftp

First of all, I know that this a duplicate topic, but the other post that I found were not useful for my situation, so I decided to create a new one.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to get a file from one FTP server and upload it to another FTP server.

I'm using this code:

```
$ftp_server = "ftp_server";
$ftp_user_name = 'ftp_username' ;
$ftp_user_pass = 'ftp_pass' ;
$localDir = "full/path/";
$serverDir = "full/path/";

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

if (ftp_get($conn_id, $localDir, $serverDir, FTP_BINARY)) {
    // ftp_fput($conn_id, $file, $fp, FTP_ASCII))
}
```

The problem that I have is when you use `ftp_put` command, it requires a local file, but this file it's not on my computer, so I can't upload it to the other ftp.

Is there a way to upload the file that I just got with `ftp_get` function into another server using `ftp_put`? Without the need to download it first on your PC?

Thanks!

Comment: You wont be able to do the with ftp with out being on the box. If you could use ssh. You might be able to start a file transfer remotely.

Comment: Here is FTP file upload example 
I hope you help full.  http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `ftp_get` and `ftp_put` can operate with files only, not folders.

Use `ftp_get` to download a file from the first server to a local temporary folder/file. And then use `ftp_put` to upload the temporary file to the second server.

---

If you want to avoid using a temporary file, you can download the file to memory using `ftp_fget` and re-upload to the second server using `ftp_fput`.

- [PHP: How do I read a .txt file from FTP server into a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18392321/850848#43505825)
- [Transfer in-memory data to FTP server without using intermediate file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27103587/850848)