# Edit an XML file on a FTP folder

Tags: php, xml, ftp

I've to add a new child on an XML tag using PHP.

I've created a little PHP script to open FTP connection to the folder where is XML file to edit and use SimpleXML to edit and add new child to that file.

```
<html lang="it">
    <head>
        <title>Modifica Fattura</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body style="text-align: center;">
        <h2 class="text-center">Modifica</h2>
            <form style="display: inline-block;" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="nome_file" placeholder="Inserisci il nome del file">
            <br>
            <select name="banca">
                <option value="000000936">INT</option>
                <option value="000092413">BIO</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="invia" value="Modifica XML">
        </form>
        <?php
        $ftp_server = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
        $ftp_username = "xxxxxxx";
        $ftp_password = "xxxxxxx";
        $conn_ftp = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die ("Non posso connettermi al server FTP");
        $login_ftp = ftp_login($conn_ftp,$ftp_username,$ftp_password);
        if ($login_ftp){
            if (isset($_POST['nome_file'])) {
                $nome_file = $_POST['nome_file'];
                $fp = fopen($nome_file,'w');
                $banca = $_POST ['banca'];
                $xml = simplexml_load_file($nome_file);
                if ($xml){
                    $fatt_primo = $xml->FatturaElettronicaBody;
                    $pagamento = $fatt_primo->addChild('DatiPagamento');
                    $dettaglio_pagamento = $pagamento->addChild('DettaglioPagamento');
                    $dettaglio_pagamento->addChild('IBAN', $banca);
                    $xml->asXML($nome_file);
                }
                fclose($fp);
            }
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expect that code to append two tags inside `<FatturaElettronicaBody>`.

---

I've that XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:FatturaElettronica xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2" versione="FPR12" xsi:schemaLocation="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2 http://www.fatturapa.gov.it/export/fatturazione/sdi/fatturapa/v1.2/Schema_del_file_xml_FatturaPA_versione_1.2.xsd">
  <FatturaElettronicaHeader>
    <DatiTrasmissione>
      <IdTrasmittente>
        <IdPaese>IT</IdPaese>
        <IdCodice>1122</IdCodice>
      </IdTrasmittente>
      <ProgressivoInvio>2</ProgressivoInvio>
      <FormatoTrasmissione>FPR12</FormatoTrasmissione>
      <CodiceDestinatario>SSDPV</CodiceDestinatario>
      <ContattiTrasmittente>
        <Telefono>1223111</Telefono>
        <Email>email@email.it</Email>
      </ContattiTrasmittente>
    </DatiTrasmissione>
    <CedentePrestatore>
      <DatiAnagrafici>
        <IdFiscaleIVA>
          <IdPaese>IT</IdPaese>
          <IdCodice>88855443</IdCodice>
        </IdFiscaleIVA>
        <Anagrafica>
          <Denominazione>REREWRWE</Denominazione>
        </Anagrafica>
        <RegimeFiscale>RF17</RegimeFiscale>
      </DatiAnagrafici>
      <Sede>
        <Indirizzo>VIA PIPPO</Indirizzo>
        <CAP>06000</CAP>
        <Comune>ROMA</Comune>
        <Provincia>RM</Provincia>
        <Nazione>IT</Nazione>
      </Sede>
      <Contatti>
        <Telefono>12321321</Telefono>
        <Email>EMAIL@EMAIL.IT</Email>
      </Contatti>
      <RiferimentoAmministrazione>7</RiferimentoAmministrazione>
    </CedentePrestatore>
    <CessionarioCommittente>
      <DatiAnagrafici>
        <IdFiscaleIVA>
          <IdPaese>IT</IdPaese>
          <IdCodice>00123321321</IdCodice>
        </IdFiscaleIVA>
        <CodiceFiscale>00123321321</CodiceFiscale>
        <Anagrafica>
          <Denominazione>FRITTTROP</Denominazione>
        </Anagrafica>
      </DatiAnagrafici>
      <Sede>
        <Indirizzo>VIA ELSI</Indirizzo>
        <CAP>00100</CAP>
        <Comune>ROMA</Comune>
        <Provincia>RM</Provincia>
        <Nazione>IT</Nazione>
      </Sede>
    </CessionarioCommittente>
  </FatturaElettronicaHeader>
  <FatturaElettronicaBody>
    <DatiGenerali>
      <DatiGeneraliDocumento>
        <TipoDocumento>TD01</TipoDocumento>
        <Divisa>EUR</Divisa>
        <Data>2019-04-08</Data>
        <Numero>12</Numero>
        <ImportoTotaleDocumento>384.30</ImportoTotaleDocumento>
        <Causale>Fattura</Causale>
      </DatiGeneraliDocumento>
    </DatiGenerali>
    <DatiBeniServizi>
      <DettaglioLinee>
        <NumeroLinea>1</NumeroLinea>
        <Descrizione>TEST</Descrizione>
        <PrezzoUnitario>250.00</PrezzoUnitario>
        <PrezzoTotale>250.00</PrezzoTotale>
        <AliquotaIVA>22.00</AliquotaIVA>
      </DettaglioLinee>
      <DatiRiepilogo>
        <AliquotaIVA>22.00</AliquotaIVA>
        <ImponibileImporto>315.00</ImponibileImporto>
        <Imposta>69.30</Imposta>
        <EsigibilitaIVA>I</EsigibilitaIVA>
      </DatiRiepilogo>
    </DatiBeniServizi>
  </FatturaElettronicaBody>
</p:FatturaElettronica>
```

and i want to append inside  another two tags like that :

```
<FatturaElettronicaBody>
  <DatiPagamento>
    <DettaglioPagamento>
      <IBAN>12312312</IBAN>
    </DettaglioPagamento>
  </DatiPagamento>
</FatturaElettronicaBody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Opening FTP connection does not make other functions magically access files on the FTP server. They still work with local files. Neither does your `fopen` have any effect on the rest of the code.*

---

SimpleXML functions do support URL wrappers. If you have [URL wrappers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) enabled in PHP, you can simply use an FTP URL in `simplexml_load_file` and `asXML` calls. Though FTP URL wrapper needs to set [context option `overwrite`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.ftp.php#refsect1-context.ftp-options) to allow overwriting an existing file. And SimpleXML does not allow context options. So you have to delete the existing file before saving it (the `unlink` call).

```
$ftp_server = "ftp.example.com";
$ftp_username = "username";
$ftp_password = "password";

if (isset($_POST['nome_file'])) {
    $nome_file = $_POST['nome_file'];
    $url = "ftp://$ftp_username:$ftp_password@$ftp_server/$nome_file";
    $banca = $_POST ['banca'];
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    if ($xml){
        $fatt_primo = $xml->FatturaElettronicaBody;
        $pagamento = $fatt_primo->addChild('DatiPagamento');
        $dettaglio_pagamento = $pagamento->addChild('DettaglioPagamento');
        $dettaglio_pagamento->addChild('IBAN', $banca);
        unlink($url);
        $xml->asXML($url);
    }
}
```

This is easy, but inefficient. It involves three connections to the FTP (for reading, deleting and writing).

Also note that if your credentials include some special symbols, you need to URL-encode them.

---

For a more efficient solution, download the XML to memory, edit it in memory and upload it back.

Some references for that:

- [PHP: How do I read a .txt file from FTP server into a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18392321/850848#43505825)
- [Transfer in-memory data to FTP server without using intermediate file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27103587/850848#43539323)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution, i'm working on it. i've always some problem because i cannot load external entity with simplexml_load_file so at this point i think that i've to download file in local memory and reupload it on ftp